# Limit text to size of input box with css

Tags: html, css

Current behavior is, when i add text in textarea till the end, i am still able to add texts in bottom wherein the lines in first move top. I want the number of characters be limited to width and height of textbox. I couldn't find a way yet. 
resize:none and overflow:hidden only disabled resize and hided scrollbars. Please favour with a solution.

My current html:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="status" class="input" autofocus></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
.input{
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    resize: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;

}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsodfkzu/11/

To demonstrate:

This is the right amount of characters this textarea can accomodate
[image]

But, it still accept even more characters and as a result, textarea doesn't look good like below:
[image]

I don't want more text being added beyond tenth line. Not sure if there's  a way to restrict.

Comment: You can only limit the text length, with `maxlength` property, now to have that match the width and/or height, you will have to add some logic using js to decide how many characters should go in there, you will have to accommodate for the font and font size, and if your textbox is responsive and resizes as the screen resizes.

Comment: You're so right @ZohirSalakCeNa .In addition to width and height, even the font size matters. I ain't sure if there is a way to atleast restrict expansion of textbox with increase in characters.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with scrollbars.

Answer (score -1):

An `<input>` element with a maximum length of 10 characters:

```
<input maxlength="number">

<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="status" class="input" maxlength="10" autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: Am sorry . Here maxlength is something which need to be predicted. I am trying to restrict characters based on size of screen . i would better suggest you to go through comments of the question for better understanding